# How to write $K$ as sum of $N$ integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to write integer $K$ as sum of $N$ positive integers with minimum variance?

Obviously when $N|K$ the solution is each of integers being $\frac KN$ and the variance would be zero. But how about when this not the case?

I know that the answer is some of them being $\lfloor\frac KN \rfloor$ and $\lfloor \frac KN \rfloor +1$, but I'm looking for an analytic solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what "smoothing" is?

**Hint:** Show that if $a \geq b+2$ then $(a-1)^2 + (b+1)^2 < a^2 + b^2$.

This proves that when the variance is minimal, each pair of integers must differ by at most 1 (otherwise we can reduce the variance further).

Hence, your claim follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't get your hint and how it is related to my question! would you mind explaining more or introducing me some useful references?

Comment: I think what Lin tries to say is if $a \geq b+2$ i.e., a,b differ more than 1,
$(a-1)^2 + (b+1)^2 < a^2 + b^2$ i.e., their current variance $a^2+b^2$ can be reduced by substracting 1 from a and adding 1 to b.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But how the variance is related to sum of their squares? And this inequality says that the sum of squares after manipulating is greater than before manipulation!

Comment: 1.yes, you're right,should be $(a-1)^2 + (b+1)^2 < a^2 + b^2$             2.$variance=((a-(\frac{a+b}2))^2+(b-(\frac{a+b}2))^2)=(a^2+b^2-2(\frac{a+b}2)(a+b)+2(\frac{a+b}2)^2)$ since a+b=c, only$a^2$ and $b^2$ matter.

Comment: @mahdi I got the sign incorrect. Variance is calculated as the sum of squares minus the square of the mean.